# Best method of organizing database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design, qsqlquery

MORE DETAILS:

**Both of you recomend using JOIN. But the main problem is how to assign multiple SUBJECTS PER EACH CLASS without using multiple duplicate values. I will have ~200 de classes, with ~30 subjects per class. That means if 2 classes share the same 20 subjects, i will have 40 rows, all with "class_id = 1" but with "subjects_Id =1, subjects_id=2, etc" Its not very ergonomic. Any other ideas? Thanks for your time!**

So, I am here again asking for your time and help friends.

I have a database that its almost ok. But I am stuck at trying how to link multiple values from a table to on collumn on another.

Let me be more explicit.

I have this table:

```
    CLASSES
id | class_name | Matters   | 
-----------------------------
1  | Class1     | 13.4.2013 | 
2  | Class2     | 14.4.2013 |
```

And this table:

Subjects

```
mat_id | show title | 
-----------------
   1   | English    | 
   2   | French     |
```

Now the problem is this. Each CLASS (e.g. CLASS1) should be able to study more Subjects at once. For example, CLASS 1 should be linked with subject (mat_id) 1, 3, 5, 6.

How to do this without repeating myself, and optimize the database? I tought that I should do it like so, but its not convenient :

CREATE A NEW TABLE named

SUBJECTS_PER_CLASS

```
id | class_id   | mat_id    |
----------------------------
1  | 1          | 1         | 
2  | 1          | 3         |
```

BUT then I dont know how to query it. Any ideas? Any help will be greatly appreciated!

THANKS!

Comment: You are describing a many to many relationship in a normalized database.  If you don't know what that means, I've heard good things about the book, Database Design for Mere Mortals.

Comment: that's exactly what you do. have an intermediate table to handle the linkages between your two main tables. this is called a many-to-many relationship.

Comment: yes, but i really need to have multiple identical "class_id" in the "subjects_per_class"? I mean is there no other way to assign more "mat_id"'s for each class_id? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Yes, the same class_id occurs multiple times in the subjects_per_class table, once for every subject that the class studies. That is the correct structure, which allows you to enforce uniqueness at the RDBMS level on class and subject.

Comment: ok, so that is it. Thank you all for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
 * 
FROM 
  CLASSES 
JOIN 
  SUBJECTS_PER_CLASS 
ON 
  CLASSES.ID = SUBJECTS_PER_CLASS.class_id
JOIN 
  Subjects 
ON 
  Subjects.id = SUBJECTS_PER_CLASS.mat_id
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use `join` command.

[Reference 1](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

[Reference 2](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp)